# How to include HBS template in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, client-side, handlebars.js, jasmine, specs

I am building a client-side web application in javascript. To build the templates I have used HandleBars.js templates, i.e. .hbs files.
I am using Jasmine framework for writing the specs for the JavaScript Code.
But I am stuck on loading the .hbs templates from the source files in the specs.

Using the Jasmine-Jquery ([Link](http://www.jayway.com/2012/04/17/configuring-jasmine-to-work-with-maven-and-jquery-fixtures/)) plugin I have included the static html templates.

This is part of a sample template :

```
<li>
  <div class="fixedText">
    <div class="middleItem">Name</div>
    <div class="midItemValue" style = "margin-right: 0.6rem;">
      <input id = "textNewGroupName" type="text" style = "width : 300px;" maxlength="300" name="name" value="{{name}}">
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

included in the hbs file. Because of the similar dynamic values (here name) in the templates I am unable to use the static fixture method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found below example by the link that I given in the question, and that fixture is used for HTML**

```
 loadFixtures('myfixture.html');

// Run test
some.methodToTest();

// Expect that the methodToTest has modified the content in the div
expect($('#fixtureId')).to...;
```

**I found the answer  for HBS also, and it is as follows:-**

1. Instead of loading `myfixture.html`, I loaded my `HBS file`.
2. Moreover the same can be done by   var t = readFixtures('myFixture.hbs').
3. Another way be to use `Handlebars.compile('myFixture.hbs')`